# How to pass strong-typed model as data param to jquery ajax post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

Is there an easy way to pass my strong-typed view model as the data parameter to this jquery ajax call?  Every example I've seen, I'd have to build the json myself e.g. { Property : "Value", etc. }.  Isn't there some luscious js helpers/codz teh do this?

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/mycontroller/myaction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: <== Here
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data.success) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever find a good workable answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper that used the `JavascriptSerializer`:

```
public static IHtmlString ToJson<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, object data)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return new HtmlString(serializer.Serialize(data));
}
```

And call it like:

```
@Html.ToJson(myData)
```

I also wrote a helper to do this (you could just steal the code or use the Nuget package):

https://github.com/paultyng/FluentJson.NET

You can create JSON in a Razor view like this (note the Knockout extension methods):

```
    @JsonObject.Create()
        .AddProperty("name", "value")
        .AddProperty("childObject", c => {
            .AddProperty("childProperty", "value2")
        })
```

This would produce JSON similar to this:

```
{"name":"value","childObject":{"childProperty":"value2"}}
```

It uses the JSON.NET serializer, not the built in one, you could easily adapt its code to your own uses and the built in one if you didn't want an additional dependency.

Comment: could be tasty; I'm not that fluent with mvc internals, but validating the model and all that in the controller is wired up if I simply make sure I match up my ViewModel Property names and all that?  No need to add any other funky junky props to the json obj?

Comment: Yeah, the [`DefaultModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) (which is used by default) should wire that all up for you and apply any data annotations you have used in your model.

Comment: I found out that this would not work on a post back because I am looking to post back changes in the model.

Comment: Yeah then your best bet is something like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) (which is included in MVC4), it allows you to create a JS model (which you could create from your server side model) bind it to input elements, and then serialize it back to the server.

Comment: if you put that as your answer, I'll choose it.