# Write a webservice method with both URI and DataContract class parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, datacontract

How can I get a web service method to access parameters in the URI and complex POST data?

I have a web service method with some parameters in the URI:

```
"/api/{something}/{id}"
```

I also have a class marked with DataContract/Member attributes that I want the webservice method to accept. Note that my class contains a subclass also marked with DataContract/Member attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class MoreData{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SubClass SubData {get; set;}
}
```

My method declaration looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke( Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/api/{something}/{id}")]
public MyWebSvcRetObj Update(string something, string id)
```

How would I get my Update method to also accept the MoreData class? I've been able to write methods like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke( Method = "POST")]
public MyWebSvcRetObj Update(MoreData IncomingData)
```

but only if the URI did not specify any parameters, and the URI would look like

```
"api/Update"
```

Ultimately I want my users to be able to something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost/site/api/things/12345
    type: 'POST'
    data: {
        SomeString: 'I am a string'
        SubData: {
           //...more data
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried putting a Stream as the final parameter in the Update method, but that doesn't seem to work for classes that have subclasses like the example I gave. It ends up having key/value pairs like "SubData[SomeSubDataProp]" : "Val". That seems wrong to me. I've also tried adding a MoreData parameter as the final param in the Update method, but I get an error that says it was expecting a stream (because it's expecting raw data). Is what I am trying to do possible? Or perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

**UPDATE**

As Faizan Mubasher wrote, my users will be able to send post data if my web method looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", 
        UriTemplate = "/v1/{something}/{id}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
    )]
    [Description( "Update " )]
    public void Update( MoreData Incoming, string something, string id )
```

With the client looking like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/app/api/something/12345',
    contentType: 'application/json',                  //need to specify type
    data: JSON.stringify({                            //note the "stringify" call
        SomeString: 'hello, world',
        SubClass: {
            SubStr: 'hello, again',
            SubInt: 98765
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think so it is a proper way to use POST method. Why you are specifying {something}/{id} in URI while you are sending data in JSON? Didn't understand this thing.

Comment: I'd like my users to do a GET with "api/things/123" to get some data, modify it, and do a POST with the same URI and the data from the GET  to make a change to the entity. My problem is that I "things" and "id" are both dynamic. How would I make it so that my users can specify the type of resource and the id in the URI send JSON data?

Comment: so you want GET and POST for same URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to keep same *URI* for both, **GET** and **POST**.

1. When a **GET** method is called with parameters */api/{something}/{id}*, then based on the **id**, it will return data to client that he/she can edit.
2. When editing is done, send that edited data back to server using **POST** method with same *URI* and *Id* as mentioned in **GET** request.

If it is so, then here is the solution:

To do  so, create two methods with same **UriTemplate** but with different names.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyWebSvc
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/api/{something}/{id}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    MyWebSvcRetObj GetData(string something, string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/api/{something}/{id}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,    
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string Update(MoreData IncomingData, string something, string id);       
}
```

Now, what should be the format of JSON. It is easy. In your `MoreData` class, **override** the `ToString()` method.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return js.Serialize(this);
}
```

The `JavaScriptSerializer` is available in **System.Web.Script.Serialization**. Now, to check which JSON format your service will accept, make a dummy call to your web service method and hit a break point on `object.ToString()` method.

```
MoreData md = new MoreData();
string jsonString = md.ToString(); // hit break point here.
```

When you hit break point, in `jsonString` variable, you will have json that your service will accept. So, recommend your client to send JSON in that format.

So, you can specify as much as complex types in your `MoreData` class.

I hope this will help you! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are posting JSON data to your strongly typed webservice method.

This is somewhat tangential to this topic: [How to pass strong-typed model as data param to jquery ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9379862/2638872)

One solution is to accept a `Json` object (the key-value pairs you mentioned) and deserialize into your `MoreData` type.

Comment: Yes, I am posting JSON data to my webservice method. The problem is that I cannot accept a data-contract class that represents the structure the client is sending in as POST data AND have URI parameters. If my URI template looks like "/api/{something}/{id}" and my method declaration looks like public MyWebSvcRetObj Update(MoreData IncomingData) to accept a JSON object I will get errors.

Comment: Could you please specify what decorators you use with each method?

Comment: I added the decorators I use for a method that allows me to use my "MoreData" class as a param. The decorators for the other version of the method is already on the post. The problem with the 2nd version then is that users would have to supply "localhost/site/api/Update." My requirement is that the URI would specify which resource is being updated.