# WCF REST. Call the same method from multiple UriTemplates?

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf, rest

So I've created a WCF Rest service. I want to be able to query it using JSON or XML. 
I've currently done this by creating multiple methods. Example below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/json/IsOnline", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[Description("Used to test for a valid response from the server.")]
bool IsOnlineJSON();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/xml/IsOnline", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
[Description("Used to test for a valid response from the server.")]
bool IsOnlineXML();
```

Then from the IsOnlineXML() and IsOnlineJSON() I call the same method to do my work.

I'm curious whether there is a better way to do this?

Comment: It is correct. You may need to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912454/write-a-webservice-method-with-both-uri-and-datacontract-class-parameters/21953119#21953119