# Wcf method strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wcf

I have built a WCF service which I am consuming with android client. I had this method:

```
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "syncfromserver/",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Message SyncFromServer(LocalDatabaseModel tc);
```

and it was working perfectly. Then I needed to send another parameter to the Method and I edited it like this:

```
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "syncfromserver/token={token}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Message SyncFromServer(string token, LocalDatabaseModel tc);
```

when I tried i kept getting errors, so I wanted to come to the previous working version, but now it wont work !? I have deleted all changes but it seems that the server is remembering them somehow and I keep getting 405 error, "HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed". Any help, someone ?

Comment: I will say! Your later version should work. Try swapping parameters, i.e, Message SyncFromServer( LocalDatabaseModel tc, string token); See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912454/write-a-webservice-method-with-both-uri-and-datacontract-class-parameters/21953119#21953119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by making a data contract class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CombinedObject{
       [DataMember(Name="token")]
       public string token {get; set; }    
       [DataMember(Name="model")]
       public LocalDatabaseModel model {get; set; }    

}
```

and the same class on client side, to respect the contract. After that the WCF method was:

```
   [WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "syncfromserver/",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Message SyncFromServer(CombinedObject tc);
```

and everything worked.