# How to support both GET/POST methods as well as XML/JSON/Stream

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have a WCF RESTful service which accepts multiple query parameters. Following is the service method.

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "test1?p1={p1}&p2={p2}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string test1(string p1, string p2);
```

I have following questions.

1. Is it possible to support both methods (GET, POST) within single service method.
2. Is it possible to support all input type format like (XML, JSON & Stream) within single method.

Annu Mittal

Comment: I would suggest using Web-API if you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well! Having same service with **GET** and **POST** method is doable.

1. [Write a webservice method with both URI and DataContract class parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912454/write-a-webservice-method-with-both-uri-and-datacontract-class-parameters/21953119#21953119).
2. As far as input types are concer! I think if you can understand first part, then we can have chances to accept **XML**, **JSON** and **Stream**.